# How Do I Convert Image Button's ID to Interger?

Tags: android

I am trying to convert an image button id into integer using:

```
i1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
int hello = Integer.parseInt(i1.getText().toString().replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
```

but it shows an error in `getText()`.
there is no predefined `getText()` in imageButton class.

how can i do that?

Comment: not sure about what u are asking. if you just want the button id then i1.getId will do the work.

Answer (score 1):

`ImageButton` is an `ImageView` subclass, therefore has no `getText()`. If you want to set and get some text, you should use   `Button` which inherits from `TextView`